# Pandas datetime filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to get subset of my dataframe if date is before 2022-04-22. The original df is like below

df:

```
    date       hour    value
0  2022-04-21  0       10   
1  2022-04-21  1       12   
2  2022-04-21  2       14 
3  2022-04-23  0       10   
4  2022-04-23  1       12   
5  2022-04-23  2       14
```

I checked data type by **df.dtypes** and it told me **'date'** column is **'object'**.

So I checked individual cell using **df['date'][0]** and it is **datetime.date(2022, 4, 21)**.

Also, **df['date'][0] < datetime.date(2022, 4, 22)** gave me **'True'**

However, when I wanted to apply this smaller than in whole dataframe by

**df2 = df[df['date'] < datetime.date(2022, 4, 22)]**,

it showed *TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'*

Why was this happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely still have some string dates in one of your rows thus the first element might be ok but a complete comparison of all values using "<" will fail.

Either you use timegeb's answer in the comments.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

or you convert them elementwise

```
import datetime
df['date']=[datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d') if type(d)==str else d for d in test]
```

Both methods might fail if you have an odd string in any of your rows. In that case you can use:

```
def convstr2date(d):
    if type(d)==str:
        try:    
            d = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(d),'%Y-%m-%d')
        except:
            d = np.datetime64('NaT')
    return d

df['date'] = [convstr2date(d) for d in df['date']]
```